# Updating a database with jQuery using AJAX

Tags: php, html, jquery

I'm having trouble getting this AJAX code to update my database. The code is a image that `onClick` will run the command to update the database

HTML:

```
<a>
    <img class       = "heart" 
         src         = "images/heart.png" 
         onClick     = "favUpdate(0,1)" 
         onMouseover = "this.src='images/heart_mo.png'"
         onMouseout  = "this.src='images/heart.png'"/>
</a>
```

Javascript code:

```
function favUpdate(fav_up, id_up) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'includes/fav_update.php',
            data: {favorite: fav_up, id: id_up},
            success: function(output) {
              alert('success, server says '
                            + output
                            + 'Variables passed are '+fav_up+' '+id_up);
                }, 
                    error: function() {
              alert('something went wrong, Favorite update failed');
            }
            });
}
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
    require_once('../Connections/main.php');
    $fav_update = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['favorite']);
    $fav_id     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
    $query      = "UPDATE projects SET favorite = $fav_update WHERE id = $fav_id";
    mysql_query($query, $main); 
?>
```

main.php

```
<?php
$hostname_main = "localhost";
$database_main = "test";
$username_main = "root";
$password_main = "";
$main = mysql_pconnect($hostname_main, $username_main, $password_main) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

Does anyone know why it's not updating the database and why the "option" isn't getting data for the variable?

Comment: check that query  run successfully and show us if you getting any error

Comment: Try `"UPDATE projects SET favorite = '".$fav_update."' WHERE id = '".$fav_id."'";`

Comment: also you are using obsolesce  `mysql_*` api its deprecated and will cause E_DEPRECATED error in php >=5.5 check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189

Comment: the server i'm using has php version 5.3.19, so i dont believe thats the issue, i tried to run the query in PHPMyAdmin and worked perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
    require_once('../Connections/main.php');
    $fav_update = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['favorite']);
    $fav_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
    $query = "UPDATE projects SET favorite = '".$fav_update."' WHERE id = '".$fav_id."'";
    mysql_query($query, $main); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to put single quote around `$fav_update` if its datatype is string `VARCHAR,TEXT`

```
$query = "UPDATE projects SET favorite = '$fav_update' WHERE id = $fav_id";
                                         ^           ^
```

Remove `$main` from here and try

```
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: on the alert(output) its echoing the query and the query is right and works on PHPMyAdmin

Comment: @raul5660 r us sure you have made the connection properly with database?

Comment: yes because i've been using the same connection file for multiple scripts before this, thats why i'm stumped

Answer (score 0):

Please try to debug your PHP (server side code first) :-

```
<?php
    require_once('../Connections/main.php');
    $fav_update = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['favorite']);
    $fav_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']);
    $query = "UPDATE projects SET favorite = $fav_update WHERE id = $fav_id";
    echo $query;
     mysql_query($query, $main); 
?>
```

Use $_REQUEST instead of $_POST, and call this api directly from the browser, by creating its url like `http://localhost/filename.php?favorite=somevalue1&id=somevalue2`

And check whether you got the insert in DB or not, and check the query by printing it too.

And after checking the API, please change the $_REQUEST, back to $_POST

Comment: i'm getting the right query but database still isnt being updated?

Comment: please cehck your main.php once, or post that file over here

Comment: i've checked it but the funny thing is that it works cause i actually use that connection file frequently thru out the site

Answer (score 0):

Changed php script to:

```
<?php
    require_once('../Connections/main.php');
    $fav_update = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['favorite']);
    $fav_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
    $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE projects 
                          SET favorite=%s  
                          WHERE id=%s",
                          $fav_update,
                          $fav_id);
    mysql_select_db($database_main, $main);
    $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $main) or die(mysql_error());


?>
```

hope that helps if anyone runs into the same issue